# Using /en and /fr Magento 2 multi language and domains

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, language, domain

I have a **Magento ver. 2.2** installation with **two** store views, one for English and one for French.

I want to use `/en` and `/fr` for the domains but when I do, all of the template assets try to call from `/en` and `/fr` as opposed to the root domain itself.

I am hosting through Nexcess.net and they said that it isn't on their end but they used to help with Magento 1 in this respect.

Am I missing something to be able to set the base url for each store view to `example.com/en` and `example.com/fr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you enabled **Add Store Code to Urls** in `Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Web`?

And then use

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy fr_FR

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Yes! I was trying to set the base urls. And I could not find that difference explained anywhere. Or the example. Thanks Lez!